# Tabitem header image

Tags: wpf

When I set image as Header of TabItem it looks like image in some gray area. How remove this surrouding area? 
[image]

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
<TabItem ToolTip="Элементы, в которых найдены несоответствия" Height="200" 
         Style="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderImageStyle}">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource CheckImage}"
               Margin="0"
               Height="25" Width="25" />
    </TabItem.Header>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding unmatched.vs}"
             MaxHeight="200" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VertexPresenterNotConformTemplate}" />
</TabItem>
<TabItem ToolTip="Элементы, соответствующие шаблону"
         Style="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderImageStyle}">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource UncheckImage}"
               Height="25" Width="25" />
    </TabItem.Header>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding unmatched.vs}"
             MaxHeight="200" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VertexPresenterConformTemplate}" />
</TabItem>
```

```
 <Style x:Key="TabItemHeaderImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border" 
                            Margin="0,0,-4,0"                                
                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                            CornerRadius="2,12,0,0" >
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Header"
                                          Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I wish(TabItem's headers under each other without a gray area around it):
[image]

Comment: Try smth like '<Image ... Margin="-5">`

Comment: Only the image are moved, not a heder's gray area

Comment: What is in TabItemHeaderImageStyle?

Answer (score 0):

TabItem probably has a border around it's header that's gray (thus making a shadow around an image). See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for TabItem ControlTemplate.

I'd try fiddling with the controltemplate or use an app like [WpfInspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) to see what's wrong with the template and get correct values.

Comment: A changing TabItem's template has not affect on header's position - only on appearance

Comment: Я не уверен, что понял чего ты пытаешься добиться. :)

Comment: :) В общем нужно чтобы header занимал ровно столко места, сколько прописано в его шаблоне. Остальное свободное место может быть не активно и не относится к какому нибудь tabitem-у. Сейчас, на скрине видно, область для хидеров используется полностью и верхний хидер занимает все свободное пространство по вертикали, не занятое нижним. Также ширина этой области больше, чем ширина контента с картинкой. Не понятно что надо настраивать - template для хидера или что-то другое?